# Using StreamSocket object in different pages

Tags: c#, oop, windows-phone, stream-socket-client

This may seem like a trite question as I am new to Object Oriented Programming, but I am working on a Windows Phone Application and I am curious about the _socket object within the program.

The code that I am using below works and I am sending this byte array via BlueTooth to my microprocessor through UART.

```
private async void ConnectToDevice(PeerInformation peer)
{
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.Dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            _socket = new StreamSocket();
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(peer.HostName, "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}");

            byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[5] {8,2,3,14,5} ;
            var buffer = GenerateData(bytesToSend);

            await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);

            MessageBox.Show("Connected to Bluetooth!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            _socket.Dispose();
            _socket = null;
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is take the _socket object from above and use it in a different page of my application.

Basically, this method is being executed in the MainPage and I want to have access to the populated fields of the StreamSocket in the "ConfigurationPage" that I've created.

How would I go about getting this object to the ConfigurationPage without creating a new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to declare it in a static property in your App.xaml.cs:

```
public static StreamSocket Socket { get; set; }
```

Then you can access it from anywhere in the application:

```
await App.Socket.ConnectAsync(peer.HostName, "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This would seem to make sense although now I am getting an exception when I step through the code. I added the public static property to the page and used it as you have demonstrated. I'm now getting a "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Any suggestions?

Comment: @JoshRyan Ugh, sounds bad. Make sure you're not trying to access the socket after disposing it, or while it's initializing